# Proving a statement about probability theory

Tags: calculus, probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let X be arandom variable.

Consider any constant $c\gt 0$

how to prove the following satement

$$\sum P(|X|\ge cn) \lt \infty \iff E(|X|)\lt \infty $$

My answer trail:

$E[|X|]=\sum_X|X|P_x(X)\lt \infty$

*Borel Cntelly Lemma:*

Suppose $A_1,...$ is a squence of events if $\sum P(A_n)\lt \infty$

Then, $P(\lim sup A_n)=0$

note: I dont know whether can I use this lemma or not. :(

Also by writting in this way, Can I further my answer?

$P(|X_n|\ge n \ \ \ \ i.o)=0 iff E(|X_n|)\lt \infty$

please help me. thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Y$ is a nonnegative random variable then $\mathbb{E}Y=\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left\{ Y\geq y\right\} dy$

(Are you familiar with that?)

From $P\left\{ Y\geq\lceil y\rceil\right\} \leq P\left\{ Y\geq y\right\} \leq P\left\{ Y\geq\lfloor y\rfloor\right\} $
it follows that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left\{ Y\geq n\right\} =\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left\{ Y\geq\lceil y\rceil\right\} dy\leq\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left\{ Y\geq y\right\} dy\leq\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left\{ Y\geq\lfloor y\rfloor\right\} dy=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P\left\{ Y\geq n\right\}$$

Apply this on $Y=|X|/c$.

---

**Addendum**:

If $Y$ is a nonnegative random variable then applying [Fubini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem) we find:

$$\mathbb{E}Y=\int_{0}^{\infty}xdF_{Y}\left(x\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{\left[0,x\right]}\left(y\right)dydF_{Y}\left(x\right)=$$$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{\left[0,x\right]}\left(y\right)dF_{Y}\left(x\right)dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left\{ Y\geq y\right\} dy$$

---

**Second addendum**:

Alternative route. For convenience I restrict to $c=1$ and let $X$ be nonnegative.

Define $X_n:=1_{[n,\infty)}(X)$ for $n=0,1,2,\dots$. Then $X_0=1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n=\lfloor X\rfloor$ so that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_{n}=\lfloor X\rfloor\leq X<\lfloor X\rfloor+1=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}X_{n}$$

Taking expectations we find:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left(X\geq n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}X_{n}\leq\mathbb{E}X\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}X_{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P\left(X\geq n\right)$$

Comment: I am not familiar with that :/ I dont understand How can write this form @drhab

Comment: See my my edit on that.

Comment: How can get the result, this is if and only if statment. For this question we can use chebyshev inequality?  @drhab

Comment: You don't need Chebyshev for that. $\mathbb EX\leq\sum\dots$ takes care of one side and $\sum\dots\leq\mathbb EX$ takes care of the other side.

Comment: Thank you for your helping, I am stuck in this questıon, I try to understand what you said :) @drhab

Comment: If we have $a\leq b\leq a+1$ then we have $a<\infty\iff b<\infty$.
Do you understand that?

Comment: Can you explain, so you mean we dont need the prove if and only if case? We just prove one direction @drhab

Comment: Assume that $a\leq b\leq a+1$. Then $a<\infty\implies a+1<\infty\implies b<\infty$ (because $b\leq a+1$, one side) and also $b<\infty\implies a<\infty$ (because $a\leq b$, other side). Proved is now that $a\leq b\leq a+1$ implies that $a<\infty\iff b<\infty$.

Comment: Okey I understand, Thank you so much, how can apply this on my guestion @drhab

Comment: In the second addendum take $a=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(X_n\geq n)$ and $b=\mathbb EX$. You are welcome.